# validation service isssue in formcontrol default value as null

Tags: angular, typescript

Am using Angular 10 ..Password validator Service

```
 static password(control: AbstractControl) {

        // {6,100}           - Assert password is between 6 and 100 characters
        // (?=.*[0-9])       - Assert a string has at least one number
        if (control.value.match(/^(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,100}$/)) {
          return null;
        } else {
          return { invalidPassword: true };
        }
      }
```

**Working Code**

```
this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username:'' ,
      password: ['', [ValidationService.password]]
    });
```

**Not working Code :**

```
  this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          username:'' ,
          password: [null, [ValidationService.password]]
        });
```

I Have used null...But now getting below error while loading login form

How to fix that ..Please let me know

[image]

EDIT :

**HTML**

```
          <div class="input-group mb-4">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="current-password"
              formControlName="password" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
           
              <ar-validation-message [control]="loginForm.controls.password"></ar-validation-message>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add safe navigation operator `?.` here

```
if (control.value?.match(...
```

with this code null value will pass through and won't trigger an error